# Jquery script not working if I add it to a new js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script to toggle a menu on button click. When I add the relevant jq code inside a script tag inside HTML, it works fine. But when I add it to an external file it doesn't work.

My HTML page is:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/lib/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lib/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lib/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lib/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lib/app-helper.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app/controllers/main-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app/directives/menu-ribbon-directive.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app-helper.js** is my external JS file.

Inside my JS file, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");

    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
});
```

The calling HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <menu-ribbon></menu-ribbon>
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default command-maps_hamburger-button" id="menu-toggle">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding the above script like this works perfectly:

```
<script>
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");

    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: As shown there does not appear to be a problem. Use a tool like the Chrome F12 network tab to see if the new file is being located and loaded.

Comment: Yeah appears to be fine here...check the 'Network' tab in dev tools

Comment: are you including the file after the tag that loads jquery ?

Comment: Yes. The files are getting loaded fine in the Networks tab. I can see the file and I can even get the debugger to get into the click event when I click on the button. But after the execution of the click event the entire page goes blank.

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is because I'm trying to mix AngularJS and jQuery in a wrong way. The element invoking the click event is inside an ng-controller div.